# Node chain of promises and code readability

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to send several request/responses from a node server, and because they are async, I had to dive into and start learning promises. Im using `bluebird` and `node` as well as `request` to send requests.

Im looking to establish a certificate chain, and my server is acting trusted third party. I have the following

```
function send_certificates (addr) {
    return send_csr_request(addr)
    .then(function(csr) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
         resolve(sign_device_cert(csr))}
     )}).then(function(signed_cert) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
         //another resolve here?
         resolve(send_cert(signed_cert));
       })
    });
}
```

Ideally I would like to slap on *another* request to this "promise-chain", something like `resolve(send_cert(caroot_cert))`
and just generally be able to modify this chain of reqeust/responses a bit better. I feel like there is a lot of boilerplate code just to call these methods. Is there any other, more manageable and readable way to do this?

Also I'm not sure if I need to promisify all these methods? If, say, `sign_device_cert` returns a Promise, how do I chain it with `.then()` calls?

---

EDIT

Here is my function that sends off a request..

```
function send_ca_cert(cert) {

  const url_string = "http://myaddress.com";
  var request_options = {
    url : url_string,
    proxy : my_proxy,
    body: pki.certificateToPem(cert),
    headers: { "someHeader : "somevalue"}
  };
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    request.postAsync(request_options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Sent off ca cert" );
        resolve();
      }
      reject();
    });
  });
}
```

When I call `then(send_cert).then(send_ca_cert)` i get the prints

```
Sent off ca cert
Sent off cert
```

How come they don't respect the Promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to wrap promises in promises. Do just

```
function send_certificates (addr) {
    return send_csr_request(addr)
    .then(sign_device_cert)
    .then(send_cert);
}
```

This should work in your case (at least if your code works).

Sometimes, you can't just pass the original function because it needs different arguments (or a different context). In those cases you still can avoid creating a new promise:

```
return functionReturningAPromise()
.then(otherFunctionReturningAPromise) // takes as parameter the result of the previous one
.then(function(someValue){
    return yetAnotherFunctionReturningAPromise(22, someValue);
});
```

Comment: is it inferred from the `resolve()`s what data to put into the next function? ? What if not all functions return a value or resolve?

Comment: This does not seem to work. When I do this, with the added .then(send_cert()) (after the first one) , the second one reports done before the first one, i.e. its not done sequentially..

Comment: `send_cert()` !== `send_cert`

Comment: So how do I specify parameters for it?

Comment: You don't need to add arguments manually. The `.then()` will call the function you pass with the previously resolved values as the arguments. So this should definitely work.

Comment: Guys, when i do `.then(send_cert).then(send_ca_cert)` (Both methods return Promises that resolve when a `postAsync` request returns 200) in the console, The prints from the functions arent in sequence .Both methods are identical except for a header.

Comment: The bug is probably in those functions. But please ask another question because it's no more about how to chain promises while maintaining readability.

Comment: I've edited my question, but I can ask another. Thanks for your help

Comment: Before you ask that other one, check those functions really return the promises and don't just create them.

Comment: This is weird. The problem must be elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can write code in this fashion that will increase the code readability.

```
let promise = someAsyncFunction();
  promise = promise.then((data) => { // here data is value if returned by function
return someAnotherAsyncCall();
});
promise = promise.then((data) => {// here data is value if returned by the previous function //}
  return someAnotherAsyncCall();
});
```

// Similarly you can carry on!
// Don't forget to use arrow function they also help to increase the code readability and must use return statement at the end of promises to avoid promise chain break;